# What is the chemical makeup of mealworm frass?

Tags: entomology, organic-chemistry

We have been raising mealworms for some time and while mealworm frass has proven very useful as a plant fertilizer, I started wondering about other potential uses of this leftover waste.

Can someone please explain what kind of compounds make up the frass from mealworms as percentages of overall makeup?

In particular I would like to understand how mealworm waste compares to other commonly used animal wastes used as fertilizer.

Bonus points if you can suggest ***other*** applications (than just fertilizer) for mealworm frass!